# How to segment the different attributes of a table in an image in key-value pairs using libraries like OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, text-extraction

I have various images containing unstructured data, mostly in tabular format. How do I use computer vision to identify tables, segment the different portions of the table and then extract the values in the form of key-value pairs using some OCR tool?

I am working with something like this.
[image: Click here to view image]

My idea is to segment the different portion of the table using computer vision and then using OCR on the different portions. Any kind of suggestion or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There are already many tutorials online, try to document yourself, make some attempts and once you will meet a _programming_ problem post the question/problem